# Angular JS ng-table errors TypeError: newParams reload is not a function and 10 digest iterations reached, ABort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am using the open source [Angular JS theme SB Admin](https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular) i completed lot of work on this. But i am want to add [Angular JS ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) it is throwing me following erros:

```
TypeError: a.reload is not a function
    at Object.fn (ng-table.min.js:3)
    at h.$digest (angular.min.js:106)
    at h.$apply (angular.min.js:109)
    at f (angular.min.js:71)
    at F (angular.min.js:75)
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (angular.min.js:76)
```

[Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…C%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%5C%22data](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bfor(var%20e%3D%7B%7D,l%3D0;l%3C%5Cna.length;l%2B%2B)%7Bvar%20k%3Da%5Bl%5D;e%5Bk.key%5D%3Dk.value(c,d)%7Dreturn%20e%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22,%22fn:%20function%20()%7Bvar%20a%3Dm(e);p(a,H%5Bc%5D)%7C%7C(p(a,l)%3Fn(e,a%3DH%5Bc%5D):H%5Bc%5D%3Da);return%20l%3Da%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22%5D,%5B%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bfor(var%20e%3D%7B%7D,l%3D0;l%3C%5Cna.length;l%2B%2B)%7Bvar%20k%3Da%5Bl%5D;e%5Bk.key%5D%3Dk.value(c,d)%7Dreturn%20e%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22,%22fn:%20function%20()%7Bvar%20a%3Dm(e);p(a,H%5Bc%5D)%7C%7C(p(a,l)%3Fn(e,a%3DH%5Bc%5D):H%5Bc%5D%3Da);return%20l%3Da%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22%5D,%5B%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bfor(var%20e%3D%7B%7D,l%3D0;l%3C%5Cna.length;l%2B%2B)%7Bvar%20k%3Da%5Bl%5D;e%5Bk.key%5D%3Dk.value(c,d)%7Dreturn%20e%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22,%22fn:%20function%20()%7Bvar%20a%3Dm(e);p(a,H%5Bc%5D)%7C%7C(p(a,l)%3Fn(e,a%3DH%5Bc%5D):H%5Bc%5D%3Da);return%20l%3Da%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22%5D,%5B%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bfor(var%20e%3D%7B%7D,l%3D0;l%3C%5Cna.length;l%2B%2B)%7Bvar%20k%3Da%5Bl%5D;e%5Bk.key%5D%3Dk.value(c,d)%7Dreturn%20e%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22,%22fn:%20function%20()%7Bvar%20a%3Dm(e);p(a,H%5Bc%5D)%7C%7C(p(a,l)%3Fn(e,a%3DH%5Bc%5D):H%5Bc%5D%3Da);return%20l%3Da%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22%5D,%5B%22fn:%20function%20(c,d)%7Bfor(var%20e%3D%7B%7D,l%3D0;l%3C%5Cna.length;l%2B%2B)%7Bvar%20k%3Da%5Bl%5D;e%5Bk.key%5D%3Dk.value(c,d)%7Dreturn%20e%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22,%22fn:%20function%20()%7Bvar%20a%3Dm(e);p(a,H%5Bc%5D)%7C%7C(p(a,l)%3Fn(e,a%3DH%5Bc%5D):H%5Bc%5D%3Da);return%20l%3Da%7D;%20newVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D;%20oldVal:%20%7B%5C%22data%5C%22:%5B%5D%7D%22%5D%5D)

**EDIT::** As the theme code is big, i created a small Fiddle script with only required things, i am getting the above and also, "newParams.reload is not a function and 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" errors.

Please check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smileofninja/m1cuf41e/) . Table seems to be important for my project, any advise is helpful.

Comment: can you just fiddle it out?

Comment: @KunalKakkad I am sorry, if it is a small script i would have fiddled, but it is theme as i mentioned in the question

Comment: Its hard to decode the issue this way.

Comment: I faced problem during reinitialize ng-table ( on click empty ng-table) . 
Fixed that by assigning self.tableParams = new NgTableParams();

Answer (score 4):

As i searched a lot for 2 days to find solution to this problem in many forums, i am unable to find and thanks to few people, who came along to sort this out.

Any way, i finded out the actual problem it is simple, "When you are using NgTableParams, please didnot use the 'NgTableParams'  variable as a scope variable, always try to use it as class variable".

I didn’t know the reason, why we have to use class variable. But from my point of view (my conclusion is based on errors), as scope variables in Angular JS are exposed to watchers and go for the digest cycle, it is giving this problem.

Following example works awesome :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="./dist/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/ng-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/ng-table.css">
<body ng-app="main">

<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
    <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table" export-csv="csv" ng-table-columns-binding="demo.columns">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" ng-if="true">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Age'" ng-if="true" filter="{ age: 'text'}">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!--    <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}</td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 --></div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
        controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, NgTableParams ) {
            var self = this;
            $scope.data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

        self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            }, {
                dataset: $scope.data
            });


    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: initialise `self.tableParams;`   and problem will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

by initialise `$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset:[] })` worked for me 
thank you